# Cleaning up 3 nested SQL `IF..ELSE` checking if value is NULL, to be used in `WHERE...AND`

Tags: if-statement, with-statement, sql-server-2017

I have a table with a large (>50) number of columns. I am writing a stored procedure, where the user wants to pass in (among other parameters) 3 optional parameters to filter the dataset by. Normally my code would look like

```
IF @value1 IS NULL
   IF @value2 IS NULL
      IF @value3 IS NULL
         WITH...SELECT
      ELSE
         WITH...SELECT
   ELSE
      IF @value3 IS NULL
         WITH...SELECT
      ELSE
         WITH...SELECT
ELSE
   IF @value2 IS NULL
      IF @value3 IS NULL
         WITH...SELECT
      ELSE
         WITH...SELECT
   ELSE
      IF @value3 IS NULL
         WITH...SELECT
      ELSE
         WITH...SELECT
```

but this seems to cluttered and very complex to follow, especially since `WITH` is relatively large.

Alternatively,

```
IF @value1 IS NULL AND
   @value2 IS NULL AND
   @value3 IS NULL
   WITH..SELECT
ELIF @value1 IS NULL AND
   @value2 IS NULL AND
   WITH..SELECT
ELIF ...
   WITH..SELECT
ELIF ...
   WITH..SELECT
...
```

is more readable but much slower. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

The IFs only affect the `WITH` part but I cannot put an IF inside the `WITH`. In addition, the only usage of the fields if not NULL is to constrain via
 `WHERE col1 = @value1` etc'

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Here is a sample of a `WITH` used when all values are present:

```
WITH trans AS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM myTable
     WHERE myKey = '12345'
       AND col1  = @value1
       AND col2  = @value2
       AND col3  = @value3
)
SELECT *
  FROM trans
 WHERE <additional criteria not dependent on @values>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use case in the where clause. One case with multiple when then will do.
Another crude way could be like this:

```
  DECLARE  @value1 as nvarchar(max),
         @value2 as nvarchar(max),
         @value3 as nvarchar(max)

declare @whereClause as nvarchar(max) = Select case when @value1 is null and @value2 IS NULl and @value3 is null then 'where clause 1'
                                                    when @value1 is null and @value2 IS NOT NULl and @value3 is NOT null then 'where clause 2'
                                                    else ''
```

use this where clause. I would dig up more for a best way. But the simplest would be this

Comment: +1 thank you for trying.

But performance wise, is this any different from case 2 in my case, which uses `IF..ELIF..ELSE` for such a construction? It seems the conditions will be evaluated in order so e.g `@value1 IS NULL` will be computed possibly 8 times? A system of nested `IF`s seems better, nothing there is evaluated more than once.

I was hoping there would be a better solution altogether, e.g. allowing to create these `WHERE..AND` clauses I am using these values for in a better way

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I found to clean up the code.

We write a generic `WHERE` clause which looks like

```
 WHERE myKey = '12345'
   AND (@value1 IS NULL OR col1 = @value1)
   AND (@value2 IS NULL OR col2 = @value2)
   AND (@value3 IS NULL OR col3 = @value3)
```

and then no nested `IF` is needed at all.